# App crash when click on dev settings

Tags: android, windows, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on React Native on Windows.
I am following the [tutorial](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/november/getting-started-with-react-native-android-and-couchbase-lite) but, i have a problem when i run it on my device Android (4.1.2) then it shows red screen with error message **"Unable to download JS bundle"** and when i click on menu button to enter ip address in dev settings then after click on dev setting app is crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when I tried to enter an ip address in dev settings. My app would crash over and over again and I couldn't set the option to 'off'. I fixed it by uninstalling the app from my phone and re-running it from the cli.

Answer (score 4):

To fix the **"Unable to download JS bundle"** and deploy the App on your device you need to:

**1. Create assets folder in android/app/src/main**

**2. Run following command in Project root directory**

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

After that it should work run as usual the

```
react-native run-android
```

command, and everything should be fine. Hope this works on Windows too...

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue!

Comment: Very interesting. However, now you need to updated that `index.android.bundle` file with every new change. Have we figured out why the app crashes when hitting Dev Settings and what the solution might be?